# Запустить war файл на VPS

Tags: java, tomcat, vps, war

Всем привет. Пытаюсь освоить, как запускать написанные java приложения в интернете. Взял VPS, поставил туда Томкат (для будущих мучеников: показано [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aG15ZnrO3w)). Поставил JRE. Поставил SQL (описано [здесь](https://losst.ru/ustanovka-mysql-ubuntu-16-04)). Теперь надо перенести war файл на VPS.

- через RDP (описано [здесь](https://www.xelent.ru/blog/perenos-faylov-s-lokalnogo-kompyutera-na-vds-pod-upravleniem-windows-server/)) не получилось, не коннектится мой комп к VPS почему-то
- читал, как через IDEA законнектиться, но у меня бесплатная версия, я так понял, что не получится (там в выпадающем меню нет выбора для создания war. Мое приложение на SpringBoot написано).
- пишут вроде, что сам Томкат должен иметь возможность подгружать файл и производить его полную подготовку-установку. Ткните меня носом как это сделать? Томкат высвечивал стартовую страницу. Там я тыркал в ссылку manager webapp, система отсылала на страницу ошибки, где просила прописать настройки. В результате в файле tomcat-users.xml  проставил права доступа:

```css
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

В файле context.xml изменил ссылку на:

```
<Context docBase="/opt/mywebapps/myapp.war"   path=""   reloadable="true" />
```

И осталась собственно таже проблема, как я понял, туда подсунуть мой WAR-ник, потому как заглавная страница Томката mysite.ru:49404 теперь не открывается, потому, что не находит по указанному месту war файл. Как мне подгрузить его туда на VPS ? и какой квест придется проходить дальше? (если надо, могу настройки для context и tomcat-users.xml откатить обратно)

Comment: Если я правильно помню - надо да, откатить внесённые изменения. После этого вызнать где находится папка, куда складываются war файлы (например `var/lib/tomcat9/webapps`). Положить туда файл. После этого оно должно стать доступно по пути `http://domain.zone:port/ИМЯ_WAR_ФАЙЛА`

Comment: На VPS надо ещё поставить VPN, и тогда можно пробовать подключиться.

Comment: @RomanC, а зачем VPN? У меня и без него работает...

Comment: Ребят, спасибо за ответы. Сорри, что долго не отвечал. Пока копался в теме, зацепился мимоходом за docker и начал его ковырять... а там своя бездна в которой я потонул. Короче, по вопросу для будущих страдальцев, типа меня, можно попробовать для перекачки использовать какой-нибудь файловый менеджер типа FileZilla, но насколько я смог понять нынче этот путь не используется, народ работает с контейнерами докера, поэтому стоит сразу разбираться с ним. Ещё раз спасибо!